# How to not allow copy pasted values in ui-select in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-select

I have a `dropdown list` and a `ui-select`. on the basis of dropdown value `ui-select` values are binding. but if i am directly pasting that specific values into `ui-select` it is showing as selected.
how can we prevent a `ui-select` from copy paste values?

example is shown below.

Select Query

```
                    <div class="dropdown-Finding">
                        <ui-select class="form-control dropdown-reviwerFinding-select" id="searchBarArea" onkeypress="return false;" multiple tagging tagging-label="false" ng-model="QiReviewerFindingType.selectedItems" theme="bootstrap">
                            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Reviewer Findings">{{$item.ShortDescription}}</ui-select-match>
                            <ui-select-choices repeat="qiQueryFinding in qiQueryFindings | filter:$select.search">
                                {{qiQueryFinding.ShortDescription}}
                            </ui-select-choices>
                        </ui-select>
                        <span class="carat" open-menu-by-click="searchBarArea"></span>
                    </div>
```

Comment: can you provide the code?

Comment: Would you mind giving more details on what you are trying to achieve and what is the use case? It is a bit hard to reason why you would want to block copy paste input

Comment: example provided.

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/BVaXpviCACi5sd3aw9oX?p=preview

Use these kind of code.

```
<ui-select ng-model="ctrl.person.selected" theme="select2" on-select="ctrl.onSelectCallback($item, $model)" ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" style="min-width: 300px;" title="Choose a person">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="person.email as person in ctrl.people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
  <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  <small>
    email: {{person.email}}
    age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
  </small>
</ui-select-choices>
```

I tried to figure out exact difference but I couldn't. But may be above sample will help you.